# Closure of a Fundamental Weyl Chamber

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

Can someone explain what a "closure" of a Fundamental Weyl Chamber means? I assume it is related to an algebraic closure, but I don't see how. In addition, how does the Weyl group act on it and why does it act that way?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the topological closure $\overline{C}$ ($C$ is the fundamental chamber). With respect to the topology of the ambient Euclidean space. The difference $\overline{C}\setminus C$ consist of *walls*, sections of the hyperplanes bordering $C$ (remember that those are in a bijective correspondence with the simple roots).

The Weyl group does not act on $\overline{C}$ at all in the sense it can move all the points out of the closure. More or less the exact opposite is true (presumably you are really asking about this). Each orbit of the Weyl group intersects $\overline{C}$ in a single point. The points in $C$ have trivial stabilizers. Any point $x$ on the boundary of $C$ has a non-trivial stabilizer. The stabilizer $\operatorname{Stab}_W(x)$ is generated by the simple reflections that keep $x$ fixed. In other words, these stabilizers are themselves Weyl groups of a lower rank root system.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking about. Looking at the explicit formula for a reflection, I don't see what could cause a reflection acting on a chamber/not hyperplane element to be trivial. I see that it makes sense it would fix the hyperplane elements. And since the hyperplanes don't intersect wouldn't there be one weyl element to one stabilizer.

Comment: Correction wouldn't there be two weyl elements per stabilizer, thus only two elements per stabilizer, the permutation with respect to the positive and negative of a root. This is not counting the trivial permutation.

Comment: The point $x$ may well lie on several such hyperplanes. When $x=0$ it lies on all of them. For example with a root system of type $A_3$ the hyperplanes orthogonal to $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ intersect along a line. One half of that line belongs to $\overline{C}$, and those points are stabilized by both $s_1$ and $s_2$, hence by $\langle s_1,s_2\rangle$, which is, of course, isomorphic to a Weyl group of $A_2$. The reflections corresponding to $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ are the same element in $W$, so you should not double count them.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I might understand it wrong, as I have not reviewed Lie theory for a while. I think the closure just means the inclusion of the fundamental Weyl chamber as well as the two lines(the two hyperplanes). When the Weyl group act on the fundamental Weyl chamber, it just permutes it to other different Weyl chambers. Looking at the Weyl group action on $A_{3}$ might be helpful, since this is a "typical" Lie group.

Comment: I know that for  fundamental Weyl chambers the weyl group normally permutes them, but I saw some weird theorem about reductable permutations made up of simple root permutations leaving the closure  elements fixed? In addition, the lines that bound the chamber are the hyperplanes of the base roots, right? Not the roots themselves?

Comment: I think you are right, my memory obviously slipped. However obviously I cannot answer your question on the "wierd theorem" you mentioned, as there is not much detail.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a lemma from Humphreys' intro to lie algrbras. It said that for two elements lamda and mu in the closure of a fund. Weyl chamber and an element of the weyl group, sigma. If sigma*lamda=mu, them sigma is a product of simple reflections, which fix lamda, thus lamda=mu. I don't see why this is,  why it is a special property of the closure, or what this actually means.

Comment: I think this just means $\lambda,\mu$ is in the fundamental Weyl chamber, the Weyl group permutes them strictly. Since the Weyl group permutes elements from one Weyl chamber to the other , if they turned out to be identical then the two elements must be equal. I do not remember if Humphreys has defined the closure somewhere.

Comment: See: http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math223aF11/Notes223a10.pdf

Comment: No he never defined the closure. He just brought it up with this lemma and said it is a fundamental domain. I don't really understand what a fundamental domain is.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll take a look at that.